# Add bookmark functionalities

Tags: vba, ms-word, bookmarks

Would it possibile to add some code line to [thees] [1](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/how-to-batch-convert-word-documents-into-pdf-files/)  in order to export pdf from word **having also bookmarks?** (without opening)

```
'Convert .doc or .docx to .pdf files via Send To menu

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For i= 0 To WScript.Arguments.Count -1
   docPath = WScript.Arguments(i)
   docPath = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(docPath)
   If LCase(Right(docPath, 4)) = ".doc" Or LCase(Right(docPath, 5)) = ".docx" Then
      Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
      pdfPath = fso.GetParentFolderName(docPath) & "\" & _
    fso.GetBaseName(docpath) & ".pdf"
      objWord.Visible = False
      Set objDoc = objWord.documents.open(docPath)
      objDoc.saveas pdfPath, 17
      objDoc.Close
      objWord.Quit   
   End If   
Next
```

Comment: See if objDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat does what you need.

Comment: Did you try recording a macro? That would give you the methods and syntax you need.